# Dynamic css classes in react

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

I'm trying to add css classes dynamically.

I have a array of colors that i want to get random color each time component rendered.

Here is what i did :

```
import styles from './UsersBoxItem.module.scss'
let colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 'orange'];

class UsersBoxItem extends Component {
    render() {
        let colorClass = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        colors = colors.filter(item => item !== colorClass)
        return (
            <div className={`${styles.box} ${styles.colorClass}`}>
```

I'm using `css-modules` but this `${styles.colorClass}` won't work and i got undefined.

Here's my code : https://codesandbox.io/embed/cocky-cloud-lomzr

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: use `colorClass ` instead `styles.colorClass `

Comment: but something like this won't work ? 
`.box {
  width: 35%;
  &.green{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, $success 40%, $secondary 100%);
  }
}`
@NicolòCozzani

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: sure : https://codesandbox.io/embed/cocky-cloud-lomzr @SungM.Kim

Comment: Why do you have `colors = colors.filter(item => item !== colorClass)` line?

Comment: skip it, i just copied it from my code, it will remove an item from array each time rendered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sung M. Kim solution work ok, I do not think that what do you want.

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-lewin-k3j1y

[image]

Comment: I see what you are trying to do now @Enzo.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to add actual class declarations in your CSS.

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
.pink {
  color: pink;
}
.orange {
  color: orange;
}
```

[image: Edit so.answer.57854561]

Forked sandbox
[image: working]

Comment: but in local scss file it's not possible ?